Problems with ASP.NET Core 6 Razor Pages on balanced servers (without sticky sessions)
greetings from Chile!, I'm having problems with an ASP.NET Core 6 Razor deployed on balanced servers (2 servers). This servers are not using sticky sessions flags. I'm having many scenarios like this :

Empty Login page (black screen)
After login empty page (black screen)
Bad Requests after loging app.

Refreshing web page back to normal sometimes but doing any operation turns again with the problems related above. The servers are configured under https.
I have no experience doing this without using sticky sessions.
Working with ChatGPT this help me a lot and i've doing the next things trying to fix the problem:

Cookie.
Redis to keep data.
MiddleWare proxy to validate session.
Forwarded configuration

Here code : (program.cs)
RedisCacheOptions cacheoptions = new RedisCacheOptions()
{
    Configuration = conn,
    InstanceName = "SampleInstance" + Guid.NewGuid()
};

builder.Services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
{
    options = cacheoptions;
});

builder.Services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyWebsite";
});

builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromHours(5);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.LogoutPath = $"/Licencias/Logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Account/AccessDenied";
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Login/Index";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.Events.OnSigningOut = (context) =>
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("/Login/Index");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});

App configuration :
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseMiddleware<ValidarSesionMiddleware>();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseCookiePolicy();

Thanks in advance!

Check the machine keys in IIS match between the servers, I had a similar issue recently when setting up load balancing in an MVC application:
Select Machine Key in the website or virtual directory in IIS

Click Generate Keys

Uncheck automatically Generate keys

Finally copy the generated keys to your other server
